# API req always undefined from axios POST

Tags: api, axios, mern

I had using the middleware but still getting undefined from req. I'm using axios POST method on my client side. Here is my code.

app.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import userAuth from './routes/userAuth';

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/userAuth', userAuth);

const CONNECTION_URL = process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL!;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

mongoose
    .connect(CONNECTION_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () =>
            console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`),
        );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

./route/userAuth.ts:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import { register } from '../controllers/userAuth';

const router = Router();

router.post('/register', register);

export default router;
```

../controllers/userAuth:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router as router, ErrorRequestHandler } from 'express';
import UserAuth from '../models/userAuthScema';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

export const register: ErrorRequestHandler = async ({ req, res }) => {
    console.log(req);

    if (!req) {
        res.json({ message: `Req Undefined.` });
        return;
    }

    let { userType, email, fName, lName, confirmPassword } = req.body;
    let { password } = req.body;

    const takenEmail = await UserAuth.findOne({ email });
    const passwordValidationFailed = password !== confirmPassword;

    if (takenEmail) res.json({ message: `User email has already been used.` });
    else if (passwordValidationFailed)
        res.json({ message: `Fail password validation.` });
    else {
        password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        const dbUser = new UserAuth({
            userType,
            email,
            firstName: fName,
            lastName: lName,
            password,
        });

        dbUser.save();
        res.json({ message: `Success!` });
    }

    return;
};
```

CLient Post :

```
export const registerAccount = (newAccount: RegisterConfigs) => {
    const baseURL = `http://localhost:4000`;
    const apiURL = `${baseURL}/userAuth/register`;

    const { userType, email, fName, lName, password, confirmPassword } =
        newAccount;

    const body = {
        userType: userType === UserType.employee ? 'Employee' : 'Employer',
        email: email.text,
        firstName: fName.text,
        lastName: lName.text,
        password: password.text,
        confirmPassword: confirmPassword.text,
    };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));

    axios
        .post(apiURL, JSON.stringify(body), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':
                    'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
                    'x-access-token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            },
        })
        .then((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log(error.toJSON());
        });
};
```

As you saw in my code, i'm using the express.urlencoded({ extended: true });, express.static('public');,  express.json()); middleware. I'm not sure where is the problem, I tried to make the header's content-type to application/json also but still got this problem.

ref:
[Ref1](https://dev.to/salarc123/mern-stack-authentication-tutorial-part-2-the-frontend-gen)
[Ref2](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-rest-api-with-node-express-and-mongodb-937ff95f23a5)

Comment: `async (req, res ) => ...`

Comment: omg i solved this problem. It was just a tiny {} and wasted me a lot days.... Thank you @derpirscher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by [derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095372/api-req-always-undefined-from-axios-post/72095577#comment127386023_72095372) was to remove `{}` to get `async (req, res ) => ...` .